# Determines if the input string is indeed a valid four character double literal

Tags: java, if-statement, char

I do have a question. I have to determine if the input string is indeed a valid four character double literal

> 1. Consists of exactly the following characters: ’+’, ’-’, ’.’ (decimal point), and ’0’ through ’9’
> 2. Either the ’+’ or ’-’ character may appear only as the first character
> 3. The ’.’ (decimal point) character must appear exactly once
> 4. All other characters must be the ’0’ through ’9’ characters

my big problems is to put the +- at the first character and . once

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
static boolean isValid(String s) {
        // 1
        if (s.length() != 4) return false;

        String digits = "0123456789";
        // 2
        if (s.charAt(0) != '+' && s.charAt(0) != '-' && digits.indexOf(s.charAt(0)) == -1) return false;


        byte decimalCount = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '.') decimalCount++;
                // 4
            else if (digits.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) == -1) return false;
        }

        //3
        return decimalCount == 1;
    }
```

Comment: its working fine with "-5.0" as it satisfies all 4 criteria, and "5.00" does not validate with the 2nd criteria.

Comment: 2nd says "may appear" not "needs to apear". all good - just trying to help out ;)